# Does $f(z)=z^{\frac{-3}{2}}$ have a pole at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does $f(z)=z^{\frac{-3}{2}}$ have a pole at $z=0$? If so, what is the order of the pole? If not, is $0$ essential singularity?   It seems to me that $0$ is essential singularity, but I can't prove it.

Thank you for the answers in advance!

Comment: The order of any pole is an *integer*. Is that the case here?

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: It's not meromorphic in $\Bbb C$ in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$z=0$ is not an isolated singularity of $z^{\frac{-3}{2}}$, so the answer is it's neither.  A branch point is the usual terminology.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much.